# Qt how to add more byte to array byte?

Tags: qt

i have a list byte for sending on serial port in qt.

my list byte: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 and more 00 ...
now i want make this byte's to a list with **for loop** and send to **QByteArray b** . for example see code:

```
QByteArray b("00 00 00 00 00 ....");
qDebug() << b;
```

please help for solve this problem. thank to all.

Answer (score 1):

you can append as many QString,QByteArray or char as you want into QByteArray with append() for more information please visit the [documentation page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might have meant one of two things:

1. An array filled with 100 zero bytes - see `array1` below.
2. An array filled with the strings `"00"` separated by spaces - see `array2` below.

The asserts show what properties does the array have - i.e. that it conforms with your presumed specification. This should also indicate to you that being extremely specific in questions in desirable, otherwise there are usually many ways to interpret what you mean - and I have no idea whether either of the solutions below is what you need!

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/bytearray-fill-test-53222084
#include <QtCore>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
   constexpr int N = 100;

   QByteArray array1(N, '\0');
   Q_ASSERT(array1.size() == N);
   Q_ASSERT(
       std::all_of(array1.cbegin(), array1.cend(), [](QChar c) { return c == '\0'; }));

   QByteArray array2;
   array2.reserve(N * 3 - 1);
   for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      array2.append(i ? "00 " : "00");
   }
   Q_ASSERT(array2.size() == (N * 3) - 1);
   Q_ASSERT(std::all_of(array2.cbegin(), array2.cend(), [i = 0](QChar c) mutable {
      return c == (i++ % 3 == 2 ? ' ' : '0');
   }));
}
```